# Converting number to big endian on Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, endianness

I have a user type in addresses such as 0x20005c98, which i am calling in POST method using `req.body.var`. However, I need this number in little endian so it shows 0x985c0020. Does anyone know how to convert this number to little endian in node js? Is there an easy way of doing this?? The network-byte-order npm is an option??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var n = 0x20005c98;
var s = n.toString(16)

var size = Math.ceil(s.length / 2) * 2;
while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;

var data = s.match(/.{1,2}/g);
data.push("0x");
data.reverse().join("").toString(16); // ==> "0x985c0020" (= 2556166176)
```

Comment: That printed out 2556166176 in my console?

Comment: Nope all that printed was 20005c980x not 0x985c0020

Comment: That's because there were two `reverse` in my piece of code, now it should be good. (sry again)

Answer (score 3):

2.6x faster version that's also easier to understand because it is explicitly doing what you asked.   But it does assumes a 4 byte integer.

```
var n = 0x20005c98;

function ReverseEndian(x) {
    buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4)
    buf.writeUIntLE(x, 0, 4)
    return buf.readUIntBE(0, 4)
}

ReverseEndian(n)
```

I used this to time stuff:

```
function timeit(n, x, args) {
    console.time("xxx")
    for (i=0;i<n;++i) {
        x.apply(null, args)
        }
    console.timeEnd("xxx")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [endianness](https://www.npmjs.com/package/endianness) module:

```
const endianness = require('endianness')
let buf = Buffer.from('20005c98','hex')
endianness(buf ,buf.length)  //toggles endianness in place
console.log(buf,buf.toString(16)
```